# Running mysqldump on a debian system that has gone into read-only mode

Tags: mysql, read-only

An old Debian system of mine has recently had the primary hard drive go into read-only mode due to some disk problem.  I have a MySQL database on the server that I would like to backup before trying to repair the harddrive.

Luckily I have another drive mounted which is not in read-only mode, so I should be able to run a **mysqldump** to dump the database to it.  However, I get the below error running **mysqldump**:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show fields from `xxx`': Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_b96_0.MYI' (Errcode: 30) (1)
```

This is obviously due to the fact that the primary disk is in read-only mode.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try `mount -o remount,rw /tmp`

Comment: I get: **mount: can't find /tmp in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TMPDIR environment variable to tell mysqldump where to put its temporary files, and point it to a writable location.

```
export TMPDIR=/mnt/writable_drive/tmp ; mysqldump dbname >/mnt/writable_drive/backup.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  I had to make sure the new location was writable by the 'mysql' user. (**chown -R mysql:mysql TMPDIR**)

Comment: No work for me. Got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump is trying to create some temp files on your dead disk.

Try to move /tmp to the new hard disk:

```
mkdir /mnt/newhdd/tmp
mount --bind /mnt/newhdd/tmp /tmp
```

This should allow your system to run normally until you complete the dump.

Other good options would be to: dump from a remote machine, or stop mysqld and just copy the mysql files over to a new system (which is good to do even if mysqldump works, ESPECIALLY if you have table problems).

Comment: Thanks,  I tried the mkdir and mount commands.  They ran fine, but the  "can't read/write" error still occurs.  I cannot dump from a remote machine because the MySQL server may only be accessed locally and I cannot copy the Mysql files relaibly because the tables are all InnoDB

Comment: You did replace /mnt/newhdd with the correct path to the new hard disk, right? - Also, check if user mysql has write access to the new /tmp

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to simply mount a rw filesystem on /tmp and get mysql happy, then you have some other options:

1) use the remote mysql commands; i.e. login remotely and save remotely

2) stream all output from mysqldump to a filesystem that is rw

3) tar up the entire mysql db files, once mysqld is stopped, and re-use them on a healthy system.

4) buy a new drive, attach it, boot up on a LiveCD or bootable flash, mount old and new, use dd to recreate the old on the new.

....maybe 10 other ways too.